# Python 2.7.9 Print statement with list strange output

Tags: python

Why whole argument in print function along with paranthesis is printed when only the string should have been

This is Python 2.7.9

```
import os

alist = [ 'A' ,'B']

print('Hello there')
print('The first item is ',alist[0])
print('Good Evening')

root@justin:/python# python hello.py
Hello there
('The first item is ', 'A')
Good Evening
```

Comment: Edited the question title so that someone querying on Google can easily get to it.

Comment: `()` are parentheses, although they may also be called round brackets. Braces look like this: `{}`; they are sometimes called curly brackets. And of course these are brackets: `[]`, and they may be called square brackets or sometimes plain brackets.

Comment: You are right, I agree, had posted in hurry, as question was simple and small

Answer (score 8):

In python 2 `print` isn't a function it's a statement. When you write

```
print('The first item is ',alist[0])
```

it's actually means "print me a tuple of 2 elements: `'The first item is '` and `alist[0]`"

it's equivalent to

```
a = ('The first item is ',alist[0])
print a
```

if you want to print only strings you should remove the parentheses like that:

```
print 'The first item is ',alist[0]
```

EDIT:
As guys in comments tell, you can also add

```
from __future__ import  print_statement
```

This will make `print` a function like in python 3 and your examples will work as you expected without any changes.

But I think it's useful to understand what is going on in both cases.

Comment: Removing the brace alone won't fully solve the problem, doing that will add an extra space between the string and item

Comment: Better to add at very start of code file ``from __future__ import print_function`` and then always use Python 3 style print function.

Answer (score 1):

Remember You're using python `2.7.x` in python 2, print is a statement, not a function.
You might ask why

```
print('Good Evening')
```

doesn't print

```
('Good Evening')
```

You're passing only 1 string argument hence the print statement understands that the string needs to be printed and not the parentheses.

when you do

```
print ('The first item is ',alist[0])
```

The whole output is printed thinking that there are different parts of the string having `,` as the delimiter, hence the output is

```
('The first item is ', 'A')
```

Remove parentheses while dealing with python 2 because it is not a function oriented version

Answer (score 1):

Earlier answers have explained that

```
print('The first item is ', alist[0])
```

in Python 2 is equivalent to

```
print ('The first item is ', alist[0])
```

so it prints a tuple of two items. That's because `print` is a *statement* in Python 2, not a function, so parentheses following `print` are *not* interpreted as indicating a function call.

In Python, an expression consisting of several items separated by commas creates a tuple. In some cases, parentheses are required to group the tuple into a single unit; and the `print` statement is one of those cases, otherwise each item in the comma-separated sequence is treated as a separate argument to the `print` statement.

The standard string representation of a tuple prints the enclosing parentheses and the [`repr`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#func-repr) of each tuple item. Thus any string items in the tuple are printed with their quote marks, and various escape sequences are used to represent non-ASCII characters.

If you wish to use the `print()` syntax in latter versions of Python 2 in order to make your code compatible with Python 3 then you should put

```
from __future__ import print_function
```

as the first executable statement in your script. That will mask the `print` statement and allow the `print` name to refer to the `print` function instead. Here's a short demo, running on Python 2.6.6. First, without the import:

```
print('one', 'two\n', 'three')
```

**output**

```
('one', 'two\n', 'three')
```

And with the import:

```
from __future__ import print_function
print('one', 'two\n', 'three')
```

**output**

```
one two
 three
```

FWIW, you might as well do

```
from __future__ import print_function, division
```

So you get Python 3-style behaviour of the `/` division operator too.